# animation scrollTop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to animate scrolling and the code is given below

```
    var offset = parseInt($this.offset().top) - 250;
    console.log(offset)
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 500);
```

Nothing is happening after that, scroll isn't moving, `console.log(offset)` outputs `739` but no `JS` errors. I can't provide Fiddle since the page is complex so I am asking you to guess what can be wrong or what is missing. Sorry for that.

Comment: Try with `scrollTop: offset + 'px'`.

Comment: Atleast some html has to be provided because its very difficult to guess `$this` in this scenario!! Atleast on what case you are trying to scroll the document??

Comment: @ Guruprasad Rao I added console.log(offset) so `$this` isn't issue in this case.

Comment: @D4V1D thanks for advise but not helped

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You dont need to add `px` to value. If you say your page is complex are you sure you are not trying to animate scroll some overflow div or something? See animation is working in this fiddle, probably problem is in your page but we cant help you without seeing it as whole https://jsfiddle.net/Glogo/xsd92gv1/

Comment: @D4V1D no error, just not working

Comment: @Glogo I understand that and can't provide examples and code is working but not working when I insert it to my page and have no idea how can I find the place is preventing scrolling

Comment: Can we, at least, have the event handler that triggers `html, body` animation?

Comment: @D4V1D see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jrne9461/ seems css problem

Comment: You forgot to activate jQuery on your JSFiddle... see this [updated one](https://jsfiddle.net/jrne9461/2/).